# Merge tag [render] to [rendering]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

The tags `render` and `rendering` seems to be about the same topic.

- [render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/render) 5274 questions and this Tag Excerpt:

  > Rendering is the process of generating an image from a model (or models in what collectively could be called a scene file), by means of computer programs.
- [rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rendering) 6926 questions and this Tag Excerpt:

  > Rendering refers to a computer program formatting data for display or printing.

Perhaps these tags should be merged or synonymized?

Comment: I'd be more in favor of creating disambiguated tags and burning ***both*** [tag:render] and [tag:rendering].

Answer (score 25):

If there is a meaningful difference between how these tags are *supposed* to be used, there is approximately zero chance that the existing questions using these tags respect that difference. Making one a synonym of the other seems like a no-brainer.

I propose [rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rendering) be the one that's kept, with [render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/render) made a synonym of it. Tag names are generally nouns; "rendering" (the process) is more relevant to Stack Overflow than "renders" (the result of rendering) are.

Comment: I agree. If you look at the Oxford dictionary it has six very different definitions for the word "render" so it is pretty ambiguous as it is. Making it a synonym is the kindest thing we can do to it.

Comment: "render" is a verb as well as a noun.  I would favor making the tag with fewer suffixes the primary,

Comment: @BenVoigt Tag names are typically nouns, not verbs. Compare [tag:unit-testing], [tag:sorting], [tag:authentication], [tag:validation], [tag:parsing] and [tag:debugging], where the suffixless [tag:unit-test], [tag:sort], [tag:authenticate], [tag:validate], [tag:parse] and [tag:debug] are tag-synonyms.